# How do I block-out daily timeblocks in Org agenda

Tags: org-mode, agenda

Hello I would like to create a time block that will be added to my agenda every day.

```
* Walk dog
  SCHEDULED: <2020-06-29 Mon 13:30-14:00 +1d>
```

I know this is possible with a Repeated task. But than I have to mark that task daily as DONE

I want to block out daily recurring times, without having to mark them daily as done. Items such as lunch break and walking the dog.
With the current repeated task I get a backlog of tasks.

Is there a way to automatically reset the schedule date, or mark the task as done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SCHEDULED does not mean what you think it means](https://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-Scheduling.html#Deadlines-and-Scheduling). These are daily appointments, so just add timestamps without planning keywords:

```
* Walk the dog
  <2020-06-29 Mon 13:30-14:00 +1d>
```

It will appear on the agenda every day (assuming that the file is in `org-agenda-files`)  but it's not a TODO item, so you don't have to mark it DONE.